# How do i download ubuntu to a usb through a chromebook

Tags: usb-drive, chromebook

I have a Chromebook (an Acer c720) and it doesn't have enough space for me to the unity form of Crouton instead of XFCE. How do I download it to a USB instead?

Comment: are you asking about how to install ubuntu?

Comment: @MinaMichael no well sorta. because my chromebook couldnt download all of the "unity" (through crouton) version of ubuntu i was wandering what was a command so i could download it to my usb instead

Comment: ...there's something that I don't understand here; let me get this straight, you want to download unity? just unity?

Comment: @MinaMichael no when i down load ubuntu i put the command "sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t unity" in and theres an error stating "E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)" how do i make it so it downloads to my usb

Comment: oh! well, I think you can change the directory of the terminal to the usb and then do this command. It should download there then. ... I change the terminal's directory on ubuntu like this `cd /example/example`

Comment: ...why not download the iso file from their main website?

Comment: @MinaMichael what do i put for the examples, what i mean is which is for the usb?

Comment: @MinaMichael because all the things i looked up told me to do it that way

Comment: hmmm, I'm trying to search on google where they should be located on chrome OS... in ubuntu they're in `/media/name_of_drive`

Comment: @MinaMichael alright ,let me know when you got it thank you

Answer (score 1):

All mine says is:

```
/media/removable/UNTITLED/chroots/chroots/precise is not an ext filesystem.
```

I've been looking into this, because of the small amount of space on my chromebook.

I've been able to install unity with crouton with this command:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r precise -t unity -e
```

I have a Acer Chromebook 11.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want install Ubuntu directly into a USB drive:

Format you pendrive in ext2, ext3, or ext4 (you can use Gparted to do this)

Download Chromium OS Universal Chroot Environment to your Chromebook:

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Open the Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) in developer mode and type:

`shell`

`sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce -p /media/removable/PENDRIVE_NAME`

You can install any distribution in the list of Crouton.

`sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t help`

Replace "xfce" for the distribution you want to install. 
Examples: "xiwi,xfce", "unity-desktop", "xbmc", "gnome", "gnome-desktop", ...

RUN: Open the Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) in developer mode and type:

`shell`

`sudo su`

`sh -e /media/removable/PENDRIVE_NAME/bin/startxfce4`

replace "startxfce4" for the distribution already installed

This is SLOOOOW. I recommend moving your installation to a USB DRIVE.

- MOVE UBUNTU TO A USB DRIVE:

INSTALL:
Format your pendrive in ext2, ext3, or ext4 (you can use Gparted to do this)

Open the Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) in developer mode and type:

`shell`

`sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce -p /media/removable/PENDRIVE_NAME`

RUN: 
Type in the terminal

`sudo su`

`sh -e /media/removable/PENDRIVE_NAME/bin/startxfce4`

- If you want run the USB Drive whit Ubuntu  in a Powerwashed, Another or in a New Chromebook you need to install xiwi in the Chromebook:

Download this app in Chrome Web Store:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crouton-integration/gcpneefbbnfalgjniomfjknbcgkbijom

INSTALL XIWI INTEGRATION:

Download Chromium OS Universal Chroot Environment to your Chromebook:

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) in developer mode and type:

`shell`

`sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xiwi`

- RUN: Type in the terminal

`sudo enter-chroot -c /media/removable/PENDRIVE_NAME/ startxfce4`

- If you want run only one aplication inside the ChromeOS environment type in Terminal (CRTL + ALT + t):

`shell`

`sudo startxiwi -c /media/removable/PENDRIVE_NAME/ firefox`

Replace "firefox" for the application you want open .
Examples: libreoffice , skype , gedit , KolourPaint ...

Sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 0):

OMG I GIVE UP!! ... last thing I could grab is that you can add `-p` to your command to chose in which directory should crouton be installed but I couldn't find out in what directory should your USB drive be and I'm not sure how exactly should this "-p" fit in the command. this is my source https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/README.md I'm sorry that's all I could get.

...also I just want to give you an advice, I don't think it's a good idea to install it on the USB stick; actually I think it might not work in the first place!!! :( if you can free up space by putting data on the usb device and then install crouton somewhere on the internal hard drive, that would be much better! otherwise you might encounter problems such as speed issues (the hard drive is much faster than the usb drive) and maybe even startup problems. **be careful**

That's all I have to give, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Ok the `-p` option seems to work.

This installation is not confirmed to be working yet because it is in progress for me.

Follow the instructions bellow if you want to try it out.

1. Format your usb flash drive to ext2
2. Create the folder "chroots" in your usb flash drive
3. Run the following command :

   ```
   sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t gnome -p /media/removable/your-flashdrive-name/chroots
   ```
4. Replace your-flashdrive-name by the name of your flashdrive. Make sure that you have created the folder "chroots" from step 3.

This should now run the process of download for crouton but on the flashdrive. It may take a long time to install.

I will post a comfirmation for this operation when my installation is finished.

Thanks :)